# How can I upload and parse a vcard using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vcf-vcard

I would like to be able to upload a vcard and have it parsed into my application's Model.

I am thinking that Paperclip would be a way to upload, but I have no idea how to do the parse.

I did a search on google, the only library that seems related is vpim, with mixed commentary.

Wanted to see what brilliant ideas might be out there to solve this...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it using vpim

Comment: I used the module vpmi...check it out...and then used the methods fort . contac attribute (e.g contact name and so forth).....prolly not the most elegant but it works...great for vcards.

Comment: can u share your code how u achieved it.... i am having pretty hard time parsing the vCard.

Comment: I uploaded a gem called vpim and it then creates a set of methods.  I don't have the code anymore since I changed projects.

Answer (score 3):

[vpim](https://github.com/sam-github/vpim) is a helpful gem for making and importing vCards here is how to use this...

```
gem 'vpim', '~> 13.11.11' #include this in your gemfile
```

in your controller decode vcard

```
@vcard = Vpim::Vcard.decode(params[:import_file].read)

@contact.title = @vcard.title
@contact.email = @vcard.email
@contact.first_name = @vcard.name.given
@contact.last_name = @vcard.name.family
@contact.phone = @vcard.telephones[0]
@contact.fax = @vcard.telephones[1]
@contact.address.street1 = @vcard.address.street
@contact.address.city = @vcard.address.locality
@contact.address.state = @vcard.address.region
@contact.address.zip = @vcard.address.postalcode
@contact.company_name = @vcard.org.fetch(0)
```

Another gem u could use is [vcardigan](https://github.com/brewster/vcardigan)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.